# command colcon_cd not found ros2 humble

Tags: ros, ros2, ros-humble

i want  to move to the package from any directory inside our terminal window

qrie@qrie-HP-Laptop-15-rb0xx:~/dev_ws$ colcon_cd two_wheeled_robot
colcon_cd: command not found

Comment: You did the setup as mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Colcon-Tutorial.html#setup-colcon-cd)?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you installed colcon-cd, you need to [source the colcon_cd.sh script before you can use the command](https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/user/installation.html#sh-and-compatible-shells). As an example, I installed colcon cd through apt, therefore my setup is:

```
apt install python3-colcon-cd
source /usr/share/colcon_cd/function/colcon_cd.sh
```

Following which `colcon_cd` works.